# Programming error - brought me out from the program

Tags: c++

I have a set of segment numbers. These segments are belonging to
specific objects. That means, one object has many segments. segment
Label tells which segment belongs to which object. So, now I want to
split my segment numbers with respect to object labels.

For that I have written below piece of codes. Assume, I know the number of objects (say max).

> the class Segments is defined with vector of Segment

```
Segments  mysegments;
Segments::const_iterator  itr;
vector<Segments>  segments_per_obj;

segments_per_obj.resize(max);

for (itr= mysegments.begin(); itr!= mysegments.end(); itr++){          
    segments_per_obj[itr->Label()].push_back(*itr); 
 }
```

When I compile, it doesn’t give any error.
But when I run (myprog.exe), it goes out of my program and gave error window telling that

```
myprog.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.
Please tell Microsoft about this problem.
```

Comment: @chris: how to rectify this.

Comment: The `resize` call probably should, but it would be better to call the size constructor. It half looks like you want a map, not a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Segments  mysegments;
Segments::const_iterator  itr;
vector<Segments>  segments_per_obj;


for (itr= mysegments.begin(); itr!= mysegments.end(); itr++)
{          
    int index = itr->Label();
    for (int i = segments_per_obj.size(); i <= index; ++i)
    {
        segments_per_obj.push_back(<create a new segment>);
    }

    segments_per_obj[index].push_back(*itr); 
}
```

Or as suggested use a map, looks more suitable for this case.

Comment: the loop can be replaced with `segments_per_obj.resize(index+1)`

Comment: @Kostia: thanks for the suggestion. i will try this. but, i dont get this code. segments_per_obj.push_back(<create a new segment>); what do you mean by <create a new segment>?

Comment: Create a new Segments object by calling Segments(<parameters>).

Comment: @slinga He basically fills the missing elements, you can simply pass a default constructed object there (the same thing `vector::resize()` with a single param does). If you would use a `std::map` you could have "gaps" between indices and this step wouldnt be neccessary

Answer (score 0):

segments_per_obj does not have any elements inside. So when you try to access the itr->Label() element of it, your program will crash.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Add empty Segment objects into segments_per_obj. You should add as many as the max value of itr->Label().
2. Use a map instead of vector for segments_per_obj

Comment: @priomsrb: if i follow your first suggestion, how can i do it. did not clearly get what you mean. Also, i like to work with vector rather than a map as later i want to use it as a vector. so, would it be still fast, if i first use a map and then suddenly convert it into a vector. thanks. plz explain me.

Comment: He rezises the vector before accessing it, this answere is partially wrong. It might be that `max` is to low though.

Comment: @Paranaix, The `resize` line was missing when the question was posted, so fair enough imo.

Comment: @Paranaix: so if i do map<int, Segments> then does it ok?

Comment: @slinga yes, yoo need to assign then though instead to call `push_back()` see the documentation for more details